# Elasticsearch/Kibana unable to search field

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

I am unable to search for a field via Elasticsearch query and also using Kibana.
My documents looks like this:

```
  "_index": "twitter",
  "_type": "nissan",
  "_id": "AVm3oHh1iSIXn8b-9qC1",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "id_str": "822121770627067911",
    "id": 822121770627067900,
    "text":"Super looking query"
```

I perform query:

```
  "size" : 1,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "id": 822121770627067900
    }
  }
```

and there are no hits, also tried with `id_str` field

Mapping looks like this
[mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0xUA.png)

Wierd thing for me is when I search for `text: looking` I get right result. Mapping for `text` field is also same.
Do I need to change mapping for `id_str` to `not_analyzed` or there is some tricky search.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure the type of id is long and not int as the number in your example is outside of bounds. Also when you search for id_str make sure you search for string "822121770627067900" and not number 822121770627067900. Also check if the document is present in same form as you feel using query http://localhost:9200/twitter/_search?pretty=true&q=*:*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your id field indexed?
At the top of your Settings > Indices > twitter page in Kibana you can click the orange "Refresh Field List" icon to pick up new fields not in your index-pattern initial definition. Then your id lookup should work if the id field is added.

Comment: I refreshed field list and it's working. Now I am able to search by id_str field. Can you provide me more info why it wasn't working and now after refresh it works?. Thank you very much :)